# end statement in Matlab takes 50% of time with sample code

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop

There have been posted some articles on the net about the problem that the 'end' statement of a for loop takes very much time.

I have the same problem in my code. That is why I have written this sample code with two simple functions ('start' and 'callMe') to make the problem clear for understanding.

I have two cases to check the time how long 'callMe' takes:

Case 1: The function 'callMe' has to calculate ' testOnly = testOnly + i' with 10000000 iterations.
    The ' testOnly = testOnly + i' line of code needs 48,3% of total time
    The 'end' statement of the for loop takes 49,7%

Case 2: The function 'callMe' shows the string 'wondering' in the command window.
    the line 'for i=1:1000' needs 99,6 % of total time, and the 'end' statement needs no time!

Of course I know that 10000000 calculations take less time then displaying a string. However, I am not talking about the absoult times. I am wondering why the 'end' statement in Case1 takes 49,7%. It has something to do with the simple math calculation of ' testOnly = testOnly + i'.
I have checked the time consumption of 'callMe' also with tic/toc in the 'start' function and those times correspond to the total times in 'callMe'.

In my real application I use a much more difficult code. This code is time-sensitive because I try to get a near realtime solution. We are talking about Parallel Toolbox, CUDA, indisde GPU commands etc. to speed up the code, but on the other hand such simple For/end time problems take all advantages.

So how to avoid this general 'end' problem?

```
% Case 1:---------------------
        function start()
        tic
          for i=1:10000
            callMe(1);
          end
        toc
        end

        function callMe(testOnly)
          for i=1:1000    
            testOnly = testOnly + i;  % Case 1
            %disp('wondering')        % Case 2
          end 

          %disp(testOnly)
        end

% Case 2:------------------
        function start()
        tic
          for i=1:10000
            callMe(1);
          end
        toc
        end

    function callMe(testOnly)
      for i=1:1000    
        %testOnly = testOnly + i;  % Case 1
        disp('wondering')              % Case 2
      end 

      %disp(testOnly)
    end
```

[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGalB.jpg)
[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msaX8.jpg)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want the "True" execution time of your code, the profiler is a bad option as it completely disabled JIT acceleration. It's decent for identifying bottlenecks, but the `end` is likely not the bottleneck once you enable JIT.

Comment: set `more off` in the beginning of the code

Comment: @hexer there is no solution to this problem, so you can add all the code in the world but that wouldn't generate a solution. Your variables simply need to be deallocated after your loop, so MATLAB has to clear them. Adding sample code does not make the problem any different. Also, `tic/toc` measuring of computation time isn't very accurate. Use [`timeit`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead.

Comment: Why I use tic/toc: I only wanted to compare the Profiler-times of 'callMe' with time from tic/toc to see if they are the same. I wanted to check if the time of the 'end' statement is included in the total time from toc.

Comment: The main reason was to show that the 'end' statement does not need any time in Case 2 when I display only a string, or with other words when I do not calcualte something.